# Get the number of weeks between 2 strings

Tags: php

I've been trying to figure out how to output the amount of weeks between 2 dates using strings given to my server.

Every thread I found that has potentially the same problem as me is using datetime() which I'm not extremely familiar with, and I believe uses a different structure than me.

Anyways, I can't figure this out and I've been trying for a couple of hours.

These are the strings I need to feed into the function:
From: "8/3/2015" to: "07/27/2015"
Note, the from string will change each week according to the monday from every week. Also, there are several To dates, and there will be a new one each week.

It would also be a lovely feature if it converted to months and years if it applies.

UPDATE
This is what I came up with, with the help of phplovers answer. This should successfully give you back the amount of days, unless its more than 7, then it would give you weeks, then months, then years.

Pardon the messiness.

```
                    $from = date_create($startDate);
                    $to = date_create($endDate);
                    $interval = date_diff($from, $to);

                    if( $interval->format("%a") % 7 == 0 ){
                        $amt = ($interval->format("%a") / 7);
                        if($amt == 1) {
                            $display =  $amt . " Week";
                        } else {
                            if($amt >= 4) {
                                $amt2 = $interval->format("%m");
                                if($amt2 == 1) {
                                    $display = $amt2 . " Month";
                                } else {
                                    $display = $amt2 . " Months";
                                    $amt3 = $interval->format("%y");
                                    if($amt3 == 1) {
                                        $display = $amt3 . " Year";
                                    } else {
                                        $display = $amt3 . " Years";
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                $display = $amt . " Weeks";
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        $display = ($interval->format("%a")) . " Days";
                    }
```

You'd just echo $display anywhere you needed the time difference.

Comment: Maybe `dateteim_diff`helps you out:
`<?php
$datetime1 = date_create('2009-10-11');

$datetime2 = date_create('2009-10-13');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>`

I found this [here](http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.diff.php)

Comment: @MrT But will this work for the given format? "8/3/2015" and "07/27/2015"? I can't change the format.

Comment: Build a new String in the right format. Use RegExp (\d+) to find the 3 "numbers" and build the right format.

Comment: Check the answer i've written.It abstracts everything out for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MrT stated, using date() functions you can achieve this easily:

```
$from = date_create("07/27/2015");
$to = date_create("08/03/2015");

$interval = date_diff($from, $to);

echo $interval->format("%a"); // %a will give difference in days
```

For more about formatting this take a look at [date_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php)

Comment: oh - this is a copy  :P

Comment: Right, but I wanted it in weeks and possibly months and years. How could I expand on this?

Comment: @Grumpy simply divide days by `7` and convert them to integer, which will give you weeks.

Answer (score 2):

I have used this in some earlier project. Hope this might help you.

```
function datediffInWeeks($date1, $date2)
{
    if($date1 > $date2) return datediffInWeeks($date2, $date1);
    $first = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date1);
    $second = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date2);
    return floor($first->diff($second)->days/7);
}

var_dump(datediffInWeeks('8/3/2015', '7/27/2015'));
```

Comment: I think I did try this one. It didn't seem to work with my page, it screwed up some formatting for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

First thing you need to do is convert the strings to something that is easy to work with. Unixtime is probably the easiest when you are doing comparisons. Unixtime is the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1, 1970). Here is what I would do:

```
$date_from = strtotime( '8/3/2015' ) // Change to your input
$date_to = strtotime( '07/27/2015' ) // Change to your input

$difference = $date_to - $date_from; // The seconds between these times

$seconds_in_minute = 60;
$seconds_in_hour = $seconds_in_minute * 60;
$seconds_in_day = $seconds_in_hour * 24;
$seconds_in_week = $seconds_in_day * 7;
$seconds_in_month = $seconds_in_day * 30;
$seconds_in_year = $seconds_in_day * 365;
```

Each of these variables store how many seconds are in the specific timeframe. What you can do is check agains these variables using some basic math.

```
$years = floor( $difference / $seconds_in_year );
$months = floor( ($difference - $years * $seconds_in_year ) / ( $seconds_in_month ) );
$days = floor( ( $difference - $years * $seconds_in_year - $months * $seconds_in_month ) / ( $seconds_in_day ) );
```

This is a long form example of what is happening in the [`date_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php) function in PHP. However, that function is only available post PHP 5.3, so if you are using an older version of PHP you can try this method.

Answer (score 1):

Visit: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

`$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');`

Answer (score 1):

There is an awesome PHP extension for this thing.Its called carbon.

Specifically, for your given task you can do the following(I am skipping the code of importing and stuff):

```
$dt = Carbon::create(2014, 1, 1);
$dt2 = Carbon::create(2014, 12, 31);
echo $dt->diffInWeeks($dt2);
```

The above function will give you your answer.

Also, you can use their `createFromFormat()` method to create carbon objects of date

Link: 
http://carbon.nesbot.com/

Comment: Yeah I didn't really want to work with any extensions. But good answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The 'W' date format fetches the week of the year that the date falls in.

```
$from = date('W', strtotime('07/27/2015') ) ;
$to = date('W', strtotime('8/3/2015') ) ;

//$from and $to now have the week of the year that their dates fall in.
//This simple math produces the the number of weeks from one date to the next.
$numOfWeeks = $to - $from;
```